# Range().value="=(if) ... " in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, cell

I'm a beginner. Can you please help me with the below code?

```
Range ("B2","B16").value="=if(B1="","",if(B4=B5,"Completed",""))
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: If you are simply asking about an Excel spreadsheet formula then you might have better luck at [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: 1) You need to use `.Formula` instead of `.Value`, 2) You need to double-up your double-quotes to escape them, [as detailed here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/string-data-type), and 3) Why not use `AND` : `=IF(AND(B1<>"",B4=B5),"Completed","")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its really not clear what the intended formula is, but this would be valid if you are trying to put the formula in B2 and B16:

```
Union(Range("B2"),Range("B16")).formula = "=IF(B1="""","""",IF(B4=B5,""Completed"",""""))"
```

If you are trying to put the formula in B2:B16 then:

```
Range("B2:B16").formula = "=IF(B1="""","""",IF(B4=B5,""Completed"",""""))"
```

Comment: `Range("B2:B16").formula` should work without a circular reference, because Excel will automatically move the references down as it fills down (so in B6 you will have `=IF(B5="","",IF(B8=B9,"Completed",""))`)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the alternate line with range B2:B16. More info is needed from the OP though.